# should i use addEventListener

Tags: javascript

Should I use `addEventListener` in these type cases?

```
<input id="input" type="file" onchange="fun()>
```

or

```
document.getElementById("input").addEventListener("change", function() {
  fun();
});
```

and why?

Comment: If you want support from IE8 and below, you will have to use a "polyfill" to add support for addEventListener. Google "addEventListener polyfill" to find solutions people have made for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `onchange` attribute requires the `fun` function to be in global scope. In a larger application you want to avoid this, as there might be other functions with the same name from your application or from external libraries. Or imagine building a component that is used several times on the page.

`addEventListener` can be wrapped in a closure like this and be used inside an isolated component:

```
(function(){})(
    function fun(){
         // Now other components can also have a `fun` function, without causing confusion.
         // `fun` is only defined inside the IIFE (the (function(){})() wrapper around the module).
    }
    document.getElementById("input").addEventListener("change", function() {
      fun();
    });
);
```

Comment: Plus with `addEventListener` you can add multiple events, not have to worry about forgetting to pass `this` or `event`, and more.  Also, [Unobtrusive JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) is prefered over inline handlers anyway :-)